# Read Response object

Tags: asp.net

How do I read/write Response to an array? I'm not talking about HttpWebResponse but using Response. The purpose is that I'm writing to the response to build a simple file and I need to perform a checksum on it.

Is it possible to read everything I've written to the response using the response object?

I've tried Response.OutputStream but this appears to be write only.

Update
Yes it is httpresonse but not httpwebresponse. *I think*. I think the answer may be to use Response.Filter

The other streams do not allow reading from. Checking now. Response.Filter is not working. I can not read from it either.

Comment: The `Response` property that is defined on the `Page` class _is_ of type `HttpResponse`. Why not link to the MSDN article that you mean in order to avoid any sort of ambiguity?

Answer (score 1):

I would write the content to a `byte[]`, checksum it and write it to the stream afterwards.